# React Native | Is it safe to store a json web token in state and async storage?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jwt, asyncstorage

I'm following a React Native course on Udemy and the course recommends storing the json web token in redux state and async storage for authentication/authorization. I was just wondering if this is secure enough? Or if there is a recommended alternative that is more secure or industry standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using refreshToken & accessToken and they have expiration time, yes it is high percent safe. But i prefer `realm` personally.

Comment: Thanks Vahid, very helpful. What do you use realm for? As a replacement for async storage?

Comment: ```realm``` is a mobile database, like ```sqlite```.